# Absolute value distance

Tags: calculus

Let $a$ and $b$ be in the interval $[0, 10]$, and let $a_0$ have a distance inferior to $10^{-3}$ from $a$ and $b_0$ a distance inferior to $10^{-3}$ from $b$. How close is $a_0 b_0$ from $ab$?

This has got me stuck. How can I verify this through inequalities?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: Upper bound for $a_0b_0-ab.$

For $a\leq 10-10^{-3}$ and $b\leq 10-10^{-3}$ we have $$a_0b_0<(a+10^{-3})(b+10^{-3})=ab+10^{-3}(a+b)+10^{-6}\leq$$ $$\leq ab+10^{-3}(20-2\cdot 10^{-3})+10^{-6}=$$ $$=ab+10^{-3}(20-10^{-3}).$$  Observe that in this case $a_0b_0-ab$ can be arbitrarily close to $10^{-3}(20-10^{-3}).$

For $a\leq 10-10^{-3}$ and $10-10^{-3}<b\leq 10$ we have $$a_0b_0<(a+10^{-3})10=(a+10^{-3})(b+(10-b))=$$ $$= ab+a(10-b)+10^{-3}(10)< ab+a(10^{-3})+10^{-3}(10)\leq $$ $$\leq ab+(10-10^{-3})10^{-3}+10^{-3}(10)=$$ $$=ab+10^{-3}(20-10^{-3}).$$For $10-10^{-3}<a<10$ and $10-10^{-3}<b\leq 10$ we have $$a_0b_0\leq 10^2=(a+(10-a))(b+10-b)=$$ $$=ab +a(10-b)+b(10-a)+(10-a)(10-b)<$$ $$<ab+10(10^{-3})+10(10^{-3})+10^{-6}=ab+10^{-3}(20-10^{-3}).$$

Comment: You can also say $|(a_0-b_0)-(a-b)|=$ $|(a_0-a)+(b-b_0)|\leq$ $\leq  |a_0-a|+|b-b_0|<10^{-3}+|b-b_0|<$ $10^{-3}+10^{-3}.$

Comment: A question, why do you put b as -b?

Comment: If you are referring to my A and not my comment, it was so we can conveniently add to get the third line from the first two lines: If $p<q<r$ and $x<y<z$ then $p+x<q+y<r+z.$

Comment: In your last inequality, why is it the difference between $(a_0-b_0)$ and $(a-b)$ instead of the difference between the products $a_0b_0$ and $ab$, which is the concern of my question?

Comment: Sorry .I mis read it .I will re-do it at once.

Comment: Don't worry! :)

Comment: I have given a partial A .(Upper bound only) as I am tired. It's almost 1 a.m. here.

Comment: Thanks for going through the work of staying late at night to write the answer.

Comment: Hey, @user254665, any chance you could finish the answer?

Comment: I intend to get to it within a day or two. I want to figure this out.

Comment: Oh, I see. OK! ^^